# How to get the position of a collision in Babylon.js?

Tags: babylonjs

Trying to make a click to move game in Babylon.js, so I'm trying to get the position on the plane that is being clicked on.

```
myGround.actionManager = new BABYLON.ActionManager(scene)
myGround.actionManager.registerAction(new BABYLON.ExecuteCodeAction(BABYLON.ActionManager.OnPickTrigger, function (evt) {
    console.log(evt)
}));
```

This code does not seem to tell me the point on the parent mesh that was clicked. Is it possible to get this data?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use the picking collision to find the screen and world coordinates of the point you clicked on.

The simplest code can be found here:

https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#NU4F6Y

You can also use the event from scene.onPointerObservable :

```js
cene.onPointerObservable.add((evt) => {
    if(evt.type === BABYLON.PointerEventTypes.POINTERPICK) {
        console.log(evt.pickInfo.pickedPoint)
    }
})
```

More info about picking info can be found here:

https://doc.babylonjs.com/babylon101/picking_collisions